# How to show Gridview Header on Pageload?

Tags: asp.net

Can you please help on how to show the header of gridview when I load the page. Here in my aspx page. Thanks in advance

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvProductInventory" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" class="table-responsive table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" DeleteText="Remove" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Seller" DataField="pSeller"/>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Buyer " DataField="pBuyer"/>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="QTY" DataField="pQTY" DataFormatString="{0:#,###0.000}"/>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Code" DataField="pCode" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Product" DataField="pProduct" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date From" DataField="Date1" DataFormatString ="{0:dd/M/yyyy}" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date To" DataField="Date2" DataFormatString ="{0:dd/M/yyyy}" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Total Days" DataField="TotalDays" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Pur Prem" DataField="pPurPremium" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Ave" DataField="Ave" DataFormatString="{0:#,###0.000}"/>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Net Price" DataField="NetPurPrice" DataFormatString="{0:#,###0.000}"/>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="USD" DataField="USD" DataFormatString="{0:#,###0.000}"/>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="AED" DataField="AED" DataFormatString="{0:#,###0.000}"/>
                        </Columns>
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can bind gridview with blank dataset or datatable.
Then show only gridview column.

Answer (score 2):

Set the property of grid view ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true". 
And then 
 bind the empty dataset or datatable to gridview.

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();